# I want to generate consecutive dates

Tags: python, date, datetime

I have code like this:

```
import time
from datetime import date

startyear = raw_input("start year: ")
startmonth = raw_input("start month: ")
startday = raw_input("start day: ")
endyear = raw_input("end year: ")
endmonth = raw_input("end month: ")
endday = raw_input("end day: ")

startdate = date(int(startyear), int(startmonth), int(startday))
while startdate < date(int(endyear), int(endmonth), int(endday)):
    print startdate
    startdate = startdate.replace(day=startdate.day + 1)
```

This code:

1. gets the start and end date by manual input
2. generate a list of dates between them

But the problem is, if I set up the date like, for example,

`startdate: 2012-10-28`
`enddate: 2012-11-4`

the output would be like:

```
2012-10-28
2012-10-29
2012-10-30
2012-10-31
ValueError: day is out of range for month
```

I want the output to be like:

```
2012-10-28
2012-10-29
2012-10-30
2012-10-31
2012-11-01
2012-11-02
2012-11-03
2012-11-04
```

So I want the dates to go through month. How can I do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of `startdate.replace()`, you should use `timedelta`...

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
# Get input here...
while startdate < date(int(endyear), int(endmonth), int(endday)):
    print startdate
    startdate += timedelta(days=1)
```

Comment: Ha, and yours fits the context better anyway.

Answer (score 7):

There's a module called [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) which is very useful for this kind of thing:

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY

list(rrule(DAILY, dtstart=datetime(2012, 11, 24), until=datetime(2012,11,30)))
# [datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 24, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 25, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 27, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 28, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 29, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 30, 0, 0)]
```

And has other options, for instance, by days of the week (useful to only include MO, TU, WE, TH, FR for working weeks):

```
from dateutil.rrule import MO, WE
list(rrule(DAILY, byweekday=[MO, WE], dtstart=datetime(2012, 11, 24), until=datetime(2012,11,30))
# [datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 26, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2012, 11, 28, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: +1 - I've never thought to look past `relativedelta` in `dateutil` - very cool!